# How to get list of all the pages (.aspx ) from a site and all its subsites using REST api or jQuery in SharePoint Onilne?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jquery, pages

I want get list of all the pages that are in pages library of each site/subsites in SharePoint Online. Can this be achieved with REST api or jQuery ? If so how? Anything is fine either Rest or jQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jquery and Rest Api to perform the same. Refer the code below:

```
var oPagesCollection=[];//object having url for all pages under root site and sub site
getPage("") //to get pages from root site

//call for first level subsite
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title",
method: "GET",
headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
},
success: function(subsites) {
    $.each(subsites.d.results, function() {
        getSubSites(this.ServerRelativeUrl, this.Title);
        getPage(this.ServerRelativeUrl);
    });
    console.log(oPagesCollection);
},
error: function(subsites) {},
async: false
});

//function to get n level of subsites
function getSubSites(SubSiteUrl, SubSiteTitle) {
console.log(SubSiteUrl);
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + SubSiteUrl + "/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(subsites) {

        $.each(subsites.d.results, function(index) {
            getSubSites(this.ServerRelativeUrl, this.Title);
            getPage(this.ServerRelativeUrl);
        });
    },
    error: function(subsites) {},
    async: false
});
}

function getPage(siteUrl){
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+ siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=FileRef",
method: "GET",
headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
},
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results,function(index,val){
        oPagesCollection.push(val["FileRef"]);
    });
},
error: function(rootsite) {},
async: false
});
}
```

Comment: @SantoshS mark it as answer then....

Comment: marked it Ankit