# SharePoint Restful API : How to get subsite pages with restful api

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, development

Dears,

I need help

How can I get all pages from subsite in sharepoint using Restfull API?

thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using REST API `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<listname>')` or using Search API `/_api/search/query?querytext='<query text>'`.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var siteUrl = "http://sp/sites/team/t1";
    getPages(siteUrl);
});

function getPages(siteUrl){
    $.ajax({
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Pages')/items?$select=FileRef",
        method: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.d.results,function(index,val){
                console.log(val["FileRef"]);
                //do somethings
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error: "+ data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Demo:

[How to get list of all the pages (.aspx ) from a site and all its subsites using REST api or jQuery in SharePoint Onilne?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200861/how-to-get-list-of-all-the-pages-aspx-from-a-site-and-all-its-subsites-using)

Comment: It's working fine ... many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To get all pages of a site you can use:

```
http://<subsite url>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items
```

If you don't know url of subsite, you can get all subsites:

```
http://<site url>/_api/web/webs
```